# How to count number of lines in PDF document?

Tags: counters, line-numbering

I'm using the `lineno` package to print line numbers (each page starts with number one) in the draft of my document:

`\usepackage[switch*, pagewise]{lineno}`

Is there a way to read out the number of lines in the whole document (or even per chapter) from one of the aux files?

I do only want to count the "real" text lines, not the headers and footers, so a sum of all the linenumbers would be quite useful. (Even if also floats are counted as one line each.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The last annotation in the `.aux` file made by `lineno` is of the form

```
\@LN{251}{5}
```

where `251` is the global number of counted lines and `5` is the last page number. Of course this will depend on the document.

If you say

```
\AtEndDocument{\typeout{Total number of lines: \thelinenumber}}
```

in your preamble, you'll see a message such as

```
Total number of lines: 251
```

in the log file (and on the terminal window).