# Command for automatically inserting wordcount in document?

Tags: lyx, word-count

I am using LyX, and I was wondering if there is any ERT Command for automatically inserting wordcount in a document? I am on Windows.

Comment: Related: [Is there any way to do a correct word count of a LaTeX document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534/is-there-any-way-to-do-a-correct-word-count-of-a-latex-document) (and maybe [Environment that counts words inside](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10033/environment-that-counts-words-inside)).

Comment: See the example using TeXcount (included with TeXLive) in [Average number of characters in one line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67694/average-number-of-characters-in-one-line)

Answer (score 2):

Lyx has the same problems LaTeX has to give you a proper word count.  The reasons you can read in the question [is-there-any-way-to-do-a-correct-word-count-of-a-latex-document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534/is-there-any-way-to-do-a-correct-word-count-of-a-latex-document) (as @cgnieder said in his comment).

So the best way seems to me to prepare a PDF with Lyx and count there the words.