# Work out maximum possible characters per line

Tags: tables, fontsize

I'm dynamically generating LaTeX source and compiling it. The documents contain only tables and each table cell in each column has the same width. I need to work out how many columns are required and figured the best way to do this would be to work out the total possible characters in a line and divide it by the (known) cell width. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\numexpr\textwidth/(\dimexpr2cm\relax)\relax
```

is the textwidth divided by `2cm`. Unfortunately etex infix arithmetic rounds up so you may need to adjust by +/- 1 depending on your requirements.

The question about characters per line doesn't in general have a good answer as characters are different widths in most fonts.

Comment: Is it possible to find out the width of characters in a particular font?

Comment: @ajnatural sure, but which characters? `w` is wider than `i` typically (except for tt  monospace fonts)

Comment: @ajnatural You can (roughly) calculate the [average number of characters per line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67694/average-number-of-characters-in-one-line) in a large sample of text. BTW, I did not understand why you need that count (a minimal working example can help) but I guess instead that you need really is the `tabularx` or `tabulary` packages of David Carlisle (sorry if I am wrong).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I meant if it was possible to compute this in LaTeX somehow.

Comment: @Fran You may be right, my use case is slightly more complicated than I stated - however a quick look at the package description seems promising. Thanks.