# Is there a way to tell LaTeX to use smaller margins without setting an absolute margin length?

Tags: margins, geometry

So, I generally like letting LaTeX make most of my typesetting decisions for me--- it generally knows what is typographically "good" better than I do.

One area I just haven't been able to turn control over to LaTeX for is margin size. As has [been noted before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71172/why-are-default-latex-margins-so-big), the default margins are fairly large in LaTeX. I understand that this is so in order to allow for a reasonable number of characters per line (I've seen 60-80 characters frequently quoted as the target range).

Currently, I am just setting exact margins with geometry (e.g., with `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}` in the preamble, because 60 characters is just too strange looking for me. Lines of around 80 characters I'm fine with, though.

Is there any way to tell LaTeX to set the margins larger without having to fix an absolute length (like 1 inch above)? Say by telling LaTeX to aim more for the 80 character-per-line limit?

Comment: Have you considered the `koma-script` classes (beginning with `scr`? These are designed, as I understand it, to get just this sort of setting right. (Whether it will look too strange I can't say...)

Comment: The `typearea` package that comes as part of KOMA-Script but can be used with the standard classes seems to be exactly what you want (this is probably what @cfr meant)

Comment: The [`rmpage` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/rmpage) has options such as `wider`.

Comment: @AndrewSwann The `rmpage` package with the `widish` option seems to give me just what I want. This is could be an answer, and is in fact what I've gone with. Thanks!

Comment: Dropping this link here since egreg's answer provides a helpful approach to directly specify the number of characters per line: [nicely force 66 characters per line.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59626/nicely-force-66-characters-per-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`rmpage` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/rmpage) has text width options of the form `wider`, `widest`, `narrower`, with variations like `touchwider`, `t@ouchnarrower`.  It also has text height options such as `long` and `shorter`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[wider]{rmpage}

\usepackage{lipsum} %for dummy text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

which reports

> ```
>    the width of one column = 980 (characters x 10) 
>
> Package rmpage Warning: \textwidth is too wide for comfy reading.
>
> %
> % -----------------------
> % LaTeX layout parameters
> % -----------------------
> %
>    \paperheight = 845.04684pt
>    \textheight = 634.0pt
>    \paperwidth = 597.50787pt
>    \textwidth = 430.9705pt
> ```

in the `.log` file.  A `widish` option will not be regard as too wide for comfy reading.

The package is a predecessor to the `geometry` package, but is often a useful alternative, with the added bonus of a fun and informative manual.

Answer (score 6):

I don't understand your unwillingness to use the `geometry` package. However, you can use the `layout` package to see what lengths you can touch in order to customize the margins, and how they look in your document. Then you can adjust the size of `\textwidth` or `\hoffset` and check the results:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{layout} % show a page layout
\setlength{\hoffset}{0.0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{.85\paperwidth}
\usepackage{blindtext}  % dummy text
\begin{document}
\layout
\blinddocument 
\end{document}
```

Then, setting a text width to 80 characters should be rather obvious with a monospaced font, but with a proportional font it simply isn't possible. A workaround could be obtain a good [Average number of characters in one line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67694/average-number-of-characters-in-one-line) and change `\textwith` accordingly.

But if your problem is simply some homesickness of Word's style, the simplest way is use the `wordlike` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{wordlike}
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Take a look also to the `savetrees` package (just change "*wordlike*" by "*savetrees*" in the above MWE).